# Landé $g$-factor - Derivation in Simon's Solid State Basics

Tags: quantum-mechanics, magnetic-fields, angular-momentum

For an atom in an external magnetic field $\mathbf B$, the Hamiltonian contains a term of the form
$$ \hat H = \mu_B \mathbf B \cdot (\mathbf L + g\mathbf S), $$
where $\mathbf L$ and $\mathbf S$ are the orbital and spin angular momenta of all the electrons in the atoms put together, and $g = 2$ is the $g$-factor for a spin-$\frac 1 2$ particle.

In Steven Simon's *The Oxford Solid State Basics*, Section 19.4, it is claimed that this Hamiltonian is equivalent to

$$ \hat H = \widetilde g \mu_B \mathbf B \cdot \mathbf J, $$
where $\mathbf J = \mathbf L + \mathbf S$ is the total angular momentum, and
$$ \widetilde g = \frac 1 2 (g+1) + \frac 1 2 (g-1) \left[ \frac {S(S+1) - L(L+1)}{J(J+1)}\right]$$
is the Landé $g$-factor.

The author claims that the derivation of this result is "not difficult". He starts by writing
$$ \mathbf B \cdot (\mathbf L + g\mathbf S) = \mathbf B \cdot \mathbf J \left[ \frac{(\mathbf L + g\mathbf S) \cdot \mathbf J}{|\mathbf J|^2}\right], \qquad (\star)$$
and then he goes on to show that the expression in the square brackets is equal to
$$ \frac 1 2 (g+1) + \frac 1 2 (g-1) \left[\frac{|\mathbf S|^2 - |\mathbf L|^2}{|\mathbf J|^2} \right].$$

However, equation $(\star)$ looks plain wrong! This manipulation is not legitimate maths. If $\mathbf x, \mathbf y, \mathbf z$ are arbitrary vectors, it's simply not true that $\mathbf x . \mathbf y = (\mathbf x \cdot \mathbf z) (\mathbf y \cdot \mathbf z) / |\mathbf z|^2$.

I may have missed a subtlety. The author points out that, in this part of the book, the Hamiltonian is only going be used to compute matrix elements between eigenstates of $J_z$, where the $z$-axis is the direction of the external magnetic field. Therefore, equation $(\star)$ only needs to hold when taking matrix elements between eigenstates of $J_z$. But be that as it may, I still don't see why $(\star)$ should hold.

What am I missing?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The correct mathematical analogue is rather:
$$
x\cdot (y+g z) \leftrightarrow \frac{[x\cdot (y+z)][(y+z)\cdot (y+gz)]}{(y+z)^2}
$$
You are correct though, both expressions are not the same in general, for arbitrary vectors, the RHS involving an addition projection in the $y+z$ direction. You can actually calculate the difference to be:
$$
\frac{[x\cdot (y+z)][(y+z)\cdot (y+gz)]} {(y+z)^2}-x\cdot (y+g z) = \frac{[x\times (y+z)]\cdot[(y+z)\times(y+gz)]} {(y+z)^2}
$$
However, since you are dealing with operator, and not numbers, there are some commutation issues that are not visible in your analogy. It turns out that the previous formula still holds in this context, since it does not need the commutation of $(x+y)^2$ with the component of the vectors.

In general, the Landé g-factor is not exact, it is the result of 1rst order perturbation. You should not view $(\star)$ as an equality of operators, but rather of expected values along all simultaneous eigenvectors $|J_z,J\rangle$. In this sense, it is as if $J$ and $L+gS$ are parallel, but in full rigour you should first do the true calculation (like in the [wikipedia article](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Land%C3%A9_g-factor)) and then check retrospectively that it amounts to using this shortcut.

Hope this helps.

Comment: yes my bad! corrected